# Other ways on displaying Featured Images in my Wordpress Home Page (Index.php)

Tags: php, wordpress

As the title suggest, I am looking for other methods/ways on displaying my featured images in my homepage or index.php.

I've already tried using:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150, true ); // Normal post thumbnails
add_image_size( 'featured-thumbnail', 60, 60 ); // Featured thumbnail size
```

but it's not cooperating with me, It doesnt follow my assigned size and it doesnt crop the image. I've been stuck here for days.

Do you have any other methods to suggest to display the featured image? Thank you very much and have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those lines of code you posted just setup your theme for supporting featured images, they won't actually display the images.

To display images, you need to use [`the_post_thumbnail('featured-thumbnail')`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) or a similar function.

You should also know that `add_image_size` code you have also sets up dimensions for **newly uploaded** images, *not* images that have been previously uploaded.

This is a common issue, and many people use some kind of [resizing plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) to resize existing media when adding new image sizes.

Comment: thank you @jrue for your answer. i forgot to include the

'code'the_post_thumbnail('featured-thumbnail')'code'

in my question but i am pretty sure that I already used that. anyway, i never knew that it was only applicable to newly uploaded images. 

in relation to this, any idea what would be your best work around to the previously uploaded images?

Comment: i mean, aside from the plug in?

Comment: Unfortunately, plugins are the best solution right now. There are other plugins that will convert images as they are requested. I wrote something for a project I was working on. These three functions will generate images if they don't exist: https://github.com/jrue/CalPress/blob/master/library/image-helpers.php

Comment: I have implemented your advice and it really works! FLAWLESSLY! Thank you very much @jrue! Have a great day!